# pine script background drawing offset bug

Tags: pine-script

i use `bgcolor` and it draw with not right offset, not in correspondence with the bar. Please make a simple try as `bgcolor(close > [value] ? [color1] : [color2])` and verify. I don't find how to report a bug on the website, if you have the same problem and know how to do please report the bug. Thank you.

Comment: i've found to enter in the help center, search for "feedback", a window open and at the bottm you can click on "leave feedback". i've wrote...

Comment: "I can confirm you after have opened a thread on stackoverflow and have read same experiences the pine script function bgcolor do not work properly, it do not paint always on the right bar in the browser version (it offset to the left of some bars the painting) and limited to the last bar in the android app version too (it offset to the right one bar the painting). You may try with the simple bgcolor(close > [value] ? [color1] : [color2]). Thank you for the solution."

Comment: If you make the same pheraph someone will find a solution.